# Setting Accept-Encoding,Accept-Charset,Accept-Language in HttpWebrequest throws exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

Setting Accept-Encoding,Accept-Charset,Accept-Language in HttpWebrequest throws an exception.I read in MSDN that they are restricted headers.Is there any way I can set these headers?

Thanks
vaysage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set these headers in the current version. We are looking into opening some of these up in future versions.